# Erro ao instalar o JWT/Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, jwt

Estou tentando instalar o `JWTAuth` no meu projeto. Atualizei meu `composer.json` conforme a documentação:

composer.json:

```
"require": {
"tymon/jwt-auth": "0.5.*"
}
```

Executei o comando composer update e apresentou o seguinte erro:

```
Problem 1
    - tymon/jwt-auth 0.5.4 requires namshi/jose 5.0.* -> satisfiable by namshi/jose[5.0.0, 5.0.1, 5.0.2].
    - tymon/jwt-auth 0.5.5 requires namshi/jose 5.0.* -> satisfiable by namshi/jose[5.0.0, 5.0.1, 5.0.2].
    - tymon/jwt-auth 0.5.6 requires namshi/jose 5.0.* -> satisfiable by namshi/jose[5.0.0, 5.0.1, 5.0.2].
    - tymon/jwt-auth 0.5.7 requires namshi/jose 5.0.* -> satisfiable by namshi/jose[5.0.0, 5.0.1, 5.0.2].
    - tymon/jwt-auth 0.5.8 requires namshi/jose 5.0.* -> satisfiable by namshi/jose[5.0.0, 5.0.1, 5.0.2].
    - tymon/jwt-auth 0.5.9 requires namshi/jose 5.0.* -> satisfiable by namshi/jose[5.0.0, 5.0.1, 5.0.2].
    - tymon/jwt-auth 0.5.1 requires namshi/jose 2.2.* -> satisfiable by namshi/jose[2.2.0, 2.2.1, 2.2.2].
    - tymon/jwt-auth 0.5.2 requires namshi/jose 2.2.* -> satisfiable by namshi/jose[2.2.0, 2.2.1, 2.2.2].
    - tymon/jwt-auth 0.5.3 requires namshi/jose 2.2.* -> satisfiable by namshi/jose[2.2.0, 2.2.1, 2.2.2].
    - tymon/jwt-auth 0.5.0 requires namshi/jose 2.0.* -> satisfiable by namshi/jose[2.0.0, 2.0.1, 2.0.2, 2.0.3].
    - namshi/jose 5.0.2 requires phpseclib/phpseclib ~0.3 -> satisfiable by phpseclib/phpseclib[0.3.0, 0.3.1, 0.3.10, 0.3.5, 0.3.6, 0.3.7, 0.3.8, 0.3.9] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
    - namshi/jose 5.0.1 requires phpseclib/phpseclib ~0.3 -> satisfiable by phpseclib/phpseclib[0.3.0, 0.3.1, 0.3.10, 0.3.5, 0.3.6, 0.3.7, 0.3.8, 0.3.9] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
    - namshi/jose 5.0.0 requires phpseclib/phpseclib ~0.3 -> satisfiable by phpseclib/phpseclib[0.3.0, 0.3.1, 0.3.10, 0.3.5, 0.3.6, 0.3.7, 0.3.8, 0.3.9] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
    - namshi/jose 2.2.2 requires phpseclib/phpseclib ~0.3 -> satisfiable by phpseclib/phpseclib[0.3.0, 0.3.1, 0.3.10, 0.3.5, 0.3.6, 0.3.7, 0.3.8, 0.3.9] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
    - namshi/jose 2.2.1 requires phpseclib/phpseclib ~0.3 -> satisfiable by phpseclib/phpseclib[0.3.0, 0.3.1, 0.3.10, 0.3.5, 0.3.6, 0.3.7, 0.3.8, 0.3.9] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
    - namshi/jose 2.2.0 requires phpseclib/phpseclib ~0.3 -> satisfiable by phpseclib/phpseclib[0.3.0, 0.3.1, 0.3.10, 0.3.5, 0.3.6, 0.3.7, 0.3.8, 0.3.9] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
    - namshi/jose 2.0.3 requires phpseclib/phpseclib ~0.3 -> satisfiable by phpseclib/phpseclib[0.3.0, 0.3.1, 0.3.10, 0.3.5, 0.3.6, 0.3.7, 0.3.8, 0.3.9] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
    - namshi/jose 2.0.2 requires phpseclib/phpseclib ~0.3 -> satisfiable by phpseclib/phpseclib[0.3.0, 0.3.1, 0.3.10, 0.3.5, 0.3.6, 0.3.7, 0.3.8, 0.3.9] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
    - namshi/jose 2.0.1 requires phpseclib/phpseclib ~0.3 -> satisfiable by phpseclib/phpseclib[0.3.0, 0.3.1, 0.3.10, 0.3.5, 0.3.6, 0.3.7, 0.3.8, 0.3.9] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
    - namshi/jose 2.0.0 requires phpseclib/phpseclib ~0.3 -> satisfiable by phpseclib/phpseclib[0.3.0, 0.3.1, 0.3.10, 0.3.5, 0.3.6, 0.3.7, 0.3.8, 0.3.9] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
    - Installation request for tymon/jwt-auth 0.5.* -> satisfiable by tymon/jwt-auth[0.5.0, 0.5.1, 0.5.2, 0.5.3, 0.5.4, 0.5.5, 0.5.6, 0.5.7, 0.5.8, 0.5.9].
```

Eu andei pesquisando na internet e descobri que pode ser algo relacionado ao macOSx. Minha versão do OpenSSL `php -i | grep OpenSSL`:

```
SSL Version => OpenSSL/1.0.2g
OpenSSL support => enabled
OpenSSL Library Version => OpenSSL 1.0.2h  3 May 2016
OpenSSL Header Version => OpenSSL 1.0.2h  3 May 2016
Native OpenSSL support => enabled
```

Versão do PHP `(php -v)`:

```
PHP 7.0.8-2+deb.sury.org~xenial+1 (cli) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.8-2+deb.sury.org~xenial+1, Copyright (c) 1999-2016, by Zend Technologies
    with blackfire v1.10.6, https://blackfire.io, by Blackfireio Inc.
```

Xcode:

```
Xcode Version 8.1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Esse erro se refere a dependências dessa biblioteca que você não possui, tente editar seu `composer.json` da seguinte forma:

```
"require": {
    "phpseclib/phpseclib": "*",
    "namshi/jose": "*",
    "tymon/jwt-auth": "0.5.*"
}
```

Comment: Pouco antes de você responder eu consegui solucionar o problema. Agradeço a atenção.

Comment: Sem problemas, disponha! ;)

Answer (score 2):

Consegui resolver o problema usando `composer require tymon/jwt-auth:1.0.0-alpha.3`